# Correct notion for state vector containing position, velocity and acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Consider without loss of generality, a mechanical system of one degree of freedom with generalized coordinate $x$. As far as Newtonian mechanics is considered, there is no need to include acceleration $\ddot x$ in the state vector $(x,\dot x)$ because its dependent on independent state variable $(x,\dot x)$.

However, in engineering, it often occurs that it is necessary to include higher order time derivatives in computation. For example, in the case of a differentially flat system, higher order time derivatives for the flat outputs are usually involved in inverting the system. Sometimes, the flat outputs overlap with the system states. Besides, trajectory planning usually considers higher order time derivatives to achieve jerk boundedness, etc.

Now, it seems to me that these higher order derivative terms are only kinematics in nature (for otherwise they are not independent), would it be possible to simply refer to the vector $(x,\dot x,\ddot x,...)$ as a **kinematic state**? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The kinematic state defines the coordinate references and state of an object in the space.

simply refer to the vector $(x,\dot x,~ $or$  ~ v,~ a $ or $ \dot v, ~j~$ or $~ \dot a,...)$

The solutions to  limiting jerk  involve fifth-order polynomials to provide a smooth trajectory between two way points with 8 waypoints maximum.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not what I asked for.

Comment: higher order derivatives and integrals are always kinematic with anything in motion with respect to the origin. So I am not sure what you don't understand.  Normally a positioner has an acceleration profile and a position error signal and the object is to minimize overshoot, jerk amplitude and time with defined limits rather than refer to some "state"

Comment: The "state" I believe just refers to  the endpoints and not the dynamics in between.

Comment: Dear Tony. Thank you for your help. I am looking for a name. And I'm afraid what you said about state is irrelevant. I mention trajectory generation only as an example.

Comment: like Trajectory Planning or Flight plan or Servo Profile or Motion Matrices?